SwiftUI ScrollView not scrolling to text field when a UIViewRepresentable is rendered
I'm currently developing some update in our views and we have a view which is totally made in SwiftUI. This view has ScrollView, which before we nested a UIViewRepresentable, it used to scroll to the TextField, when this field was focused.
struct PinDetailViewSwiftUI {

    var body: some View {

            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    GeometryReader { proxy in
                        let offset = proxy.frame(in: .named("scroll")).minY
                        Color(GrayColors.gray10.getColor()).preference(key: ViewOffsetKey.self, value: offset)
                    }
                    
                    if pinViewModel.isLoadingData {
                        PinDetailLoadingViewSwiftUI()
                    } else {
                        PinSectionHeaderView(title: DTTaskListTranslate.splitViewTasks.translation)
                        if !pinViewModel.tasks.isEmpty || pinViewModel.tasksHasChanged {
                            
                            NavigationLink(destination: PinTaskDetailSwiftUI(tasks: .constant(pinViewModel.tasks), selectedTask: pinViewModel.preSelectedTask, pin: pinViewModel.pinModel, userRole: project.roleType ?? .SubContractor, viewMode: .view, reassign: false), isActive: $pinViewModel.openPreSelectedTask) {
                                EmptyView()
                            }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                            
                            SwiftUI.Group {
                                TaskPreviewRepresentable(task: pinViewModel.tasks[0], userImage: .constant(nil), userRole: project.roleType ?? .SubContractor, viewModel: viewModel)
                                    .frame(height: viewModel.getHeightOfTaskPreview(task: task, userRole: project.roleType ?? .SubContractor), alignment: .center)
                            }
                            .animation(.easeInOut)
                        }
                        
                        if pinViewModel.pinModel != nil  && pinViewModel.userCanCreateTasks() {
                            NavigationLink(isActive: $pinViewModel.showTaskCreationView) {
                                PinTaskDetailSwiftUI(tasks: $pinViewModel.tasks, selectedTask: DTMediaPost.getDefaultTask(pin: pinViewModel.pinModel), pin: pinViewModel.pinModel, userRole: project.roleType ?? .SubContractor, viewMode: .create, reassign: false)
                            } label: {
                                Button(action: {
                                    if !pin.isPinClosedOrInactive {
                                        pinViewModel.showTaskCreationView.toggle()
                                    } else {
                                        pinViewModel.showPinClosedAlert.toggle()
                                    }
                                }, label: {
                                    PinCreateNewTask()
                                })
                            }
                            .frame(height: 50)
                        }
                        
                        PinSectionHeaderView(title: DTPinTranslate.pinFieldsHeader.translation)
                        
                        if !pinViewModel.datasets.isEmpty {
                            PinDatasetView(linkedDatasets: $pinViewModel.linkedRecords, records: $pinViewModel.datasets, datasetChanged: $pinViewModel.datasetChanged, showPinClosedAlert: $pinViewModel.showPinClosedAlert, pin: pinViewModel.pinModel)
                            
                            Rectangle()
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .frame(height: 1)
                                .foregroundColor(.gray.opacity(0.2))
                                .padding([.bottom, .top], 8)
                        }
                        
                        if !pinViewModel.pinFields.isEmpty {
                            
                            SwiftUI.Group {
                                ForEach(pinViewModel.pinFields, id: \.id!) { value in
                                    switch value.type! {
                                    case .number:
                                        PinTextFieldView(pinModel: $pinViewModel.pinModel, numberPinField: value as! DTNumberPinField, canEdit: pinViewModel.pinModel.canPinBeChanged)
                                    case .date:
                                        PinDateView(pin: $pinViewModel.pinModel, dtPinDateField: value as! DTPinDateField, canEdit: pinViewModel.pinModel.canPinBeChanged)
                                    case .slider:
                                        PinSliderView(pinSliderScale: value as! DTPinSliderField, pinModel: $pinViewModel.pinModel, categoryColor: $pinViewModel.pinCategoryColor, canEdit: pinViewModel.pinModel.canPinBeChanged)
                                    case .text:
                                        PinTextAreaView(textPinField: value as! DTTextPinField, canEdit: pinViewModel.pinModel.canPinBeChanged, pinModel: $pinViewModel.pinModel)
                                    case .tags:
                                        VStack {
                                            if showTagSuggestions {
                                                PinTagSuggestionView(suggestedTags: $pinViewModel.suggestedTags, recentTags: $pinViewModel.filteredRecentTags, searchedTag: $pinViewModel.currentTagBeingAdded)
                                                    .frame(height: pinViewModel.getRecentTagsHeight())
                                            }
                                            PinTagsView(showTagSuggestions: $showTagSuggestions, currentTagBeingAdded: $pinViewModel.currentTagBeingAdded, canBeEdited: pinViewModel.pinModel.canPinBeChanged, tagField: value, pin: $pinViewModel.pinModel)
                                        }
                                        
                                    case .time:
                                        PinTimeFieldView(pinModel: $pinViewModel.pinModel, timePinField: value as! DTPinTimeField)
                                    }
                                    
                                    Rectangle()
                                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                        .frame(height: 1)
                                        .foregroundColor(.gray.opacity(0.2))
                                        .padding([.bottom, .top], 8)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        
                        if !pinViewModel.visualMediaPosts.isEmpty, !isCameraOpened {
                            PinMediaView(medias: $pinViewModel.visualMediaPosts, pin: pinViewModel.pinModel, numberOfMedias: pinViewModel.numberOfElementsInPin())
                                .frame(height: pinViewModel.getTotalHeightForMediaSection())
                        }
                        
                        if !pinViewModel.mediaPosts.isEmpty,
                            !isCameraOpened {
                            PinSectionHeaderView(title: DTSharedTranslate.activity.translation)
                            
                            if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
                                PinActivityViewList(mediaPosts: pinViewModel.mediaPosts, pin: pinViewModel.pinModel, isLastPage: pinViewModel.isLastPage, pinDetailViewModel: .constant(pinViewModel), isLoading: pinViewModel.isLoadingMedia, loadNextPage: $pinViewModel.loadNextPage)
                                    .frame(height: pinViewModel.getTotalHeightForActivitySection())
                                    .animation(.easeInOut)
                                    .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
                            } else {
                                PinActivityViewList(mediaPosts: pinViewModel.mediaPosts, pin: pinViewModel.pinModel, isLastPage: pinViewModel.isLastPage, pinDetailViewModel: .constant(pinViewModel), isLoading: pinViewModel.isLoadingMedia, loadNextPage: $pinViewModel.loadNextPage)
                                    .frame(height: pinViewModel.getTotalHeightForActivitySection())
                                    .animation(.easeInOut)
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .background(Color.white)
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
            }
            .background(Color(GrayColors.gray10.getColor()))
            .coordinateSpace(name: "scroll")
            .onPreferenceChange(ViewOffsetKey.self) { value in
                if pinViewModel.galleryViewHeight >= 0.0 && pinViewModel.galleryViewHeight <= pinViewModel.kGalleryHeightConst {
                    let previousValue = pinViewModel.galleryViewHeight + value
                    if previousValue <= 0.0 {
                        pinViewModel.galleryViewHeight = 0
                    } else if previousValue >= pinViewModel.kGalleryHeightConst {
                        pinViewModel.galleryViewHeight = pinViewModel.kGalleryHeightConst
                    } else {
                        pinViewModel.galleryViewHeight = previousValue
                    }
                }
            }
     }
}


As you can see in the code above, the: PinTextFieldView, PinDateView, PinTextAreaView are all text fields, which when we tap on it, moves the scroll view and focus them.
This behaviour used to work fine, until the moment we added a new class: TaskPreviewRepresentable, which is just a XIB done in UIKit, which renders another object that we fetch from the backend.
In this view we have only a few buttons and labels, all the constraints are set up correctly, but for some reason, I still can't get the ScrollView, to scroll to the field when it's focused.
Has anyone ever faced this issue, which the ScrollView stops to focus on a text field, only because you added a UIViewRepresentable to it?
This is the code for the TaskPreviewRepresentable
struct TaskPreviewRepresentable: View, UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var task: DTMediaPost
    @Binding var userImage: UIImage?
    var userRole: RoleType
    @SwiftUI.State var viewModel: CardTaskViewModel
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> DTTaskPreview {

        let taskPreview = DTTaskPreview(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIDevice.isiPad ? viewModel.pinDetailiPadWidth - 32 : UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 32, height: self.viewModel.getHeightOfTaskPreview(task: task, userRole: userRole)))
        
        taskPreview.setupTaskStatus(taskStatus: NewTaskStatus(dtMediaPost: task))
        taskPreview.setTaskStatusLabel(value: NewTaskStatus(dtMediaPost: task).getName().lowercased())
        taskPreview.setTaskNumber(value: DTTaskListTranslate.taskListNumber.translation+" "+(task.number.unwrapped == 0 ? "-" : String(task.number.unwrapped)))
        taskPreview.setTaskDescription(value: task.title.unwrapped)
        taskPreview.setTaskCreatedOrLastModified(value: viewModel.getLastModifiedString(task: task))
        taskPreview.setAssigneeImage(image: viewModel.userImage, placeholder: task.getAssigneePlaceholder)
        
        var mainAction: TaskQuickAction?
        var secondaryAction: TaskQuickAction?
        (secondaryAction, mainAction) = viewModel.getMainAndSecondaryAction(userRole: userRole, task: task)

        if let leftAction = secondaryAction {
            taskPreview.setLeftButton(buttonSize: .medium, buttonStyle: .tertiary)
            taskPreview.setActionForLeftButton(actionName: leftAction.getOptionTranslation(), quickAction: leftAction)
        } else {
            taskPreview.hideLeftButton(hidden: true)
        }
        
        if let mainAction = mainAction {
            taskPreview.setRightButton(buttonSize: .medium, buttonStyle: .callToAction)
            taskPreview.setActionForRightButton(actionName: mainAction.getOptionTranslation(), quickAction: mainAction)
        } else {
            taskPreview.hideRightButton(hidden: true)
        }
        taskPreview.hideButtonView(hidden: (mainAction == nil && secondaryAction == nil))
        
        taskPreview.setAssigneeName(value: task.assignment?.name ?? "")
        taskPreview.setAssigneeSecondLine(value: viewModel.getAssigneeSecondLineString(task: task))
        taskPreview.setDueDateLabel(value: task.due)
        taskPreview.delegate = viewModel
        
        return taskPreview
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: DTTaskPreview, context: Context) {
        uiView.setAssigneeImage(image: viewModel.userImage, placeholder: task.getAssigneePlaceholder)
    }
    
}


